# Plotnine legend justified to left

Tags: python, plotnine

I cannot justify the legend to the left despite adding `legend_box_just="left"`. I'm using Plotnine version 0.13.0 with Python 3.11.

Code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':  pd.date_range(start="2024-01-01", periods=11, freq="W").repeat(3),
    'Variable': ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 11,
    'Value': np.random.choice(range(50), 33)
})

plot = (ggplot(df, aes(x='Date', y='Value', fill='Variable'))
        + geom_bar(stat="identity")
        + labs(title="Title")
        + theme_minimal()
        + theme(
            legend_title=element_blank(),
            legend_direction="horizontal", legend_box="horizontal",
            legend_position="top", legend_box_just="left")
        )

plot.show()
```

Plot:
[image]

How do I get the caption left justified and aligned with the title?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by left justified? Do you mean moving the legend to the left side of the graph, like this? https://i.imgur.com/eyT86II.png

Comment: @NickODell yes, just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `legend_justification=0` or `legend_justification_top=0`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':  pd.date_range(start="2024-01-01", periods=11, freq="W").repeat(3),
    'Variable': ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 11,
    'Value': np.random.choice(range(50), 33)
})

plot = (ggplot(df, aes(x='Date', y='Value', fill='Variable'))
        + geom_bar(stat="identity")
        + labs(title="Title")
        + theme_minimal()
        + theme(
            legend_justification=0,
            # legend_justification_top=0, # Alternatively, to be more specific
            legend_title=element_blank(),
            legend_direction="horizontal",
            legend_box="horizontal",
            legend_position="top",
            legend_box_just="left"
        )
    )

plot.show()
```

[image: Justifying the legend with plotnine]

This has revealed a bug i.e. the blanked legend title has been included in the justification. In the meantime you can use a negative justification factor. A fix will be out soon.

Comment: Thank you! I've been going crazy with this problem.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in v0.13.1.

Answer (score 1):

To put the legend in the upper-left hand corner, I'd suggest passing coordinates to legend_position.

Example:

```
plot = (ggplot(df, aes(x='Date', y='Value', fill='Variable'))
        + geom_bar(stat="identity")
        + labs(title="Title")
        + theme_minimal()
        + theme(
            legend_title=element_blank(),
            legend_direction="horizontal", legend_box="horizontal",
            legend_position=(0.2,0.9), legend_box_just="left")
        )
```

Plot:

[image: example plot]

Comment: Is there any way to put it outside the chart but below the left aligned title?